# what is the link between SAR memory output and free command?

Tags: linux, redhat, memory, sar, free

I now understand a bit more RAM usage in linux OS and I knwo that I can use free -h to have correct knowledge about RAM utilization in my server.

but I also have SAR that is working on my server and I don't see the link between SAR outputs and free output.

this website write some relationship between these command outputs but it is not correct for my server. why ?
https://www.catalyst2.com/knowledgebase/server-management/investigating-memory-usage-with-sar/

for instance here what I have in same time :

```
sar -f /var/log/sa/sa04 -r
Linux 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64 (XXXXX)      03/04/2024      _x86_64_        (32 CPU)

Average:    kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
229307171       394
10:15:01 AM  20288408 507419344     96.16     23956 425241152 139210760     25.57 259695284 230272148       148
10:20:01 AM  20105208 507602544     96.19     23956 425232140 139499180     25.62 259847160 230279820       348
10:25:01 AM  21172892 506534860     95.99     23956 425321436 138078624     25.36 258889072 230283168       200
10:30:01 AM  21162780 506544972     95.99     23956 425347776 138069932     25.36 258893704 230280008       216
10:35:01 AM  20702812 507004940     96.08     23956 425471328 139023364     25.53 259269580 230360248      7032
10:40:02 AM  20318412 507389340     96.15     23956 425443164 141154772     25.92 259582372 230358724      1192
10:45:02 AM  19954804 507752948     96.22     23956 425795580 141170648     25.93 259644240 230674360       196
10:50:01 AM  20096560 507611192     96.19     23956 425794692 140834740     25.87 259517620 230666828       204

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           503G         75G         19G        1.6G        408G        425G
Swap:           15G        666M         15G
```

it seems that buff/cache value 408G is not equal to kbchached+kbbuffers...
kbcached value seems to be equal to "available" output of free.

it is strange. is there a problem in SAR configuration ?

please note that these command are launched in same time and sar refresh is small enough so that RAM usage don't change a lot during the interval.

Answer (score 2):

Both `sar` and `free` get their information from `/proc/meminfo`.

[man free](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) describes exactly which values from `/proc/meminfo` correspond to its output.

- `buffers` value is `Buffers` in `/proc/meminfo`
- `cache` value is `Cached` and `SReclaimable` in `/proc/meminfo`
- `buff/cache` Sum of buffers and cache

[man sar](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sar.1.html) doesn't have such a description but from the source code of [rd_stats.c](https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat/blob/master/rd_stats.c#L329) it seems that:

- `kbcached` equals `Cached`
- `kbbuffers` equals `Buffers`.

The difference between `sar` and `free` output is in `SReclaimable` which `free` counts but `sar` does not.

Comment: thanks I agree but you will also agree that in my server the values don't match. right ? free display 408G for buf+cache whereas SAR displays : 425G+23Mo for cache+buf => values are not correct. right ?

Comment: @iostrym I have added a clarification to my answer.

Comment: also, `free -h` output is in Gibibytes where 1 G = 1 073 741 824 bytes. If you convert `sar` output to Gibibytes then it is 406 G rounded up, not 425 G.